# Unique project to join Raspberry Pi 2 running Ubuntu to a Windows domain controller

Tags: samba, raspberrypi

Our teacher gave us an unique project to join a Raspberry Pi 2 running Ubuntu to the schools windows domain controller. If we succeed they are considering creating a whole lab using Raspberry Pi 2's, thus being a very cost effective solution.

Me and my classmate are Linux boobs, him knowing a little more than I do. We installed Samba trying to join the domain that way. We've gotten as far as trying to mess with the samba configuration file. Which the only thing we've done on there is edit this line:

```
workgroup = WORKGROUP
```

to

```
workgroup = student.local
```

`student.local` is the domain name

After that we tried using the samba command to join it. Which is:

```
samba -tool domain join student.local MEMBER -Myusername -realm=student.local --dns-backend=none
```

But we get an uncaught exception error, which leads to

```
Connection to DC failed:  NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT
```

And a second one leading to

```
Connection to DC failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
```

We're still bashing our heads together in the project, researching what we can. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There shouldn't be a space between the `-` and the option that follows, when specifying commandline options. It should be in the format `program -option whatever` or `program --option whatever` (depending on the specific program), not `program - option whatever`

Answer (score 0):

According to the offical samba documentation when joining a domain you shouldn't use the samba tool.

Here is a link to the official documentation on how to join a machine to the domain [Setting Up A Member Server](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setup_Samba_as_an_AD_Domain_Member)

Something to considor is are you able to resolve the exsisting domain controller by hostname.

Also is the username and password you are using given elevated privlliges to join a domain? I think its unlikely standard users are able to join clients/servers to the domain.

You include the option  "--dns-backend=none", as far as im aware this is an option for provisioning a new domain with a seperate DNS server else where.

Ive found samba to have a real learning curve, you will uninstall and re-install it a million times and continully get it wrong, to gain a better understanding of setting up, joining and managing a domain the best way ive found is to setup your own domain and join a couple of VM (Virtual Machine) clients to it.

[Jim Shaver](https://jimshaver.net/2014/07/13/setting-up-an-active-directory-domain-controller-using-samba-4-on-ubuntu-14-04/) has written what i found to be a great tutorial on provisioning your own domain. Fire up a VM or RPI and give it ago, youll learn alot.